# facebook like button on my site only shows up after you refresh the page. does it have to do with all.js

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I used code from 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

to add a like button on the site.   I have the script tags right after the body as described and the div further down by my header, but when I load the page, the like button is not there.  but if I hit refresh its there.   my guess is that the all.js is taking too long to load and its missed somehow on the 1st load.  on the 2nd refresh, I assume the js is cached and things work as expected.

any idea how to wait on this?  I have tried putting the script in the head, at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "I have the script tags right after the body", do you mean outside of the body? If so, try putting it in side the body, but after all other element inside of the body.

```
<body> ...other code ...other code ...other code 
  <script>Put your script here</script> 
</body>
```

Comment: Could you possibly provide a link to your test page. It would help if I could inspect your code.